# How to restrict access to Chatting service only to registered websites

Tags: django, authentication, token, chat

I am making a chatting service ([something like Zendesk](https://www.zendesk.com/service/messaging/live-chat-widget)) and a website must be registered in order to use the service. There will be a *frame* which the website owner places in the .html file and the rest is up to me.

**Problem**

Anyone can start using the service right now (by reading the requests and copying them in Postman). I want a method to restrict access only to those websites that have registered to use the service when the session is started or by the messages sent from that session.

**Failed solutions (to give an idea of what I am trying to do)**

- A stupid idea was to read and send the website URL with *JavaScript* and check if it exists in the database, but that can easily be forged.
- I also tried generating unique *tokens* for each registered website, but the token is something that must be send with the request for validation and since it is something that public can see (the token is placed with the *frame*) that token is indeed meaningless. (Maybe I don't understand how *tokens* work)

At this point, seems like this is inevitable, any Ideas?

(Back-end is written in **Django 3.1** and My database tables look like this, if it helps - Ignore the details, just an overview)
[image: Database design]

Comment: You can check it using Javascript. `window.parent.location` should give you the parent (i.e. the containing web page's) URL.

Comment: So the request would contain the URL as data, right? Can't that be done with postman to start a new chat session?

Comment: That wasn't what I said, but yes, you can also use the `HTTP_REFERER` value in the `request` which _should_ also be equal to the parent URL. It can be faked with postman but who are you expecting to fake it? The end user?

Comment: Makes sense :) Solved the problem another way, thanks anyways.

Comment: All good. You may post your solution as an answer to help future visitors.